# Corrupted images in Firefox

Tags: firefox

On some pages, I have weird images (like an image from an old scratched tape of an image mixed with other images).  Even if I reload the page, I still see those images instead of the real images.  That happened occasionally.  Is it a hard-disk failure (sign that I have to change it ?) or a software failure ?

Here are some examples from [one particular page](http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-incredibly-useful-tools-built-into-twitter-bootstrap/):

Original:

[image]

Corrupted:

[image]

Original:

[image]

Corrupted:

[image]

Original:

[image]

Corrupted:

[image]

Comment: Another image : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2012/52/1356614673-3.png

Comment: The original web page here ==> http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-incredibly-useful-tools-built-into-twitter-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a problem with this site, not your browser.  When I tried editing your post to insert the uncorrupted images, I had to try several times on each one to get the upload to work.  I got repeated complaints from superuser that the file format wasn't supported.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that was my first Question :D, i do believe I saw that issue with other sites but not so sure :/ hope you're right!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with the site.
Try using ctrl+shift+delete to clean your browser's cache then reload.
It has worked for me!